# Create a query that compares dates only and truncates time

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Is there any workaround how to make an entity framework 7 query that compares ony dates and truncates time?
In framework 7 there is no DbFunctions.TruncateTime.

[github issue in framework 7 repo](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/2850)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not interested in the custom SQL approach, you can try to keep things "LINQy" and do the following:

```
from e in db.Events
    where e.Timestamp.Date == targetDateTime.Date
    select e
```

It worked for me, but I'm not really sure how the SQL translation is happening nor if the performance is acceptable.

Answer (score 3):

You can always use "FromSql" to run custom queries and to workaround limitations in EF7.

```
context.Set<TEntity>().FromSql("SELECT * FROM t ...");
```

Comment: Is it any better solution for this? Create DbFunction or something?